# How to avoid blocking the port for workflow manager for SharePoint 13

Tags: port, sharepoint-workflow

i try to install workflow manager, but while installing i got below error. I search in other site it shows some solution as disable the some services in firewall, i tried for it but it not work.
Please give me some solution over it.

Configuration for Workflow Manager
Management Database SQL Instance    SP2012.Goalsr.com\SPMSSQLSERVER
Enable SSL connection with SQL Server instance  False
Authentication  Windows Authentication
Management Database Name    WFManagementDB
RunAs Account   Administrator@GOALSR
RunAs Password  ***********
Certificate Generation Key  ***********
Workflow Manager Outbound Signing Certificate   Auto-generated
Service SSL Certificate Auto-generated
Encryption Certificate  Auto-generated
Workflow Manager Management Port    12290
HTTP Port   12291
Enable firewall rules on this computer  True
Administrators Group    BUILTIN\Administrators
Configuration for Service Bus
Management Database SQL Instance    SP2012.Goalsr.com\SPMSSQLSERVER
Enable SSL connection with SQL Server instance  False
Authentication  Windows Authentication
Management Database Name    SbManagementDB
RunAs Account   Administrator@GOALSR
RunAs Password  ***********
Certificate Generation Key  ***********
Farm Certificate    Auto-generated
Encryption Certificate  Auto-generated
HTTPS Port  9355    **Port number 9355 specified for HTTPS Port is blocked.**
TCP Port    9354
Message Broker Port 9356
Internal Communication Port Range   9000 - 9004 **Port number 9002 specified for Internal Communication Port Range is blocked.**
Enable firewall rules on this computer  True
Administrators Group    BUILTIN\Administrators

Comment: It's a helpful explanation and solution for **[Port number specified for internal communication Port Range is blocked](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-port-is-blocked/)**

Answer (score 0):

What is your SQL server instance?

I was using .\MSSQL2012 and received the same error. For some reason it did not know to connect to port 1433 (default SQL server port).

The solution was to use
.\MSSQL2012,1433